# Low quality when copying bitmap through Context Menu

Tags: plotting, graphics, export

The easiest method to share your immediate MMA results to non-MMA users among your peers is to just copy the result onto an email and send it.

Figure below shows a `Plot` result in MMA 11.3 and the copied plot using MMA's context menu on an email client. The resolution/quality of the copied plot is really bad when in comparison with the generated plot in MMA. Also note that when copying plots from MMA, you don't get to copy the legends.
[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Example MWE to get the same plot:

```
data = {{300, 9887.194597268477}, {600, 14617.627888223156}, {1200, 
    17472.238222603686}, {2400, 22591.04051553365}, {4800, 
    28243.41293535661}, {10000, 36748.2517500408}, {20000, 
    53289.72684007045}, {40000, 80376.84548931476}};
nlm4 = NonlinearModelFit[
  data, (a + b x + c x^2 + d x^3 + e x^4), {a, b, c, d, e}, x]
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[nlm4[x], {x, 0, 40000}], PlotRange -> All, 
  ImageSize -> Large, Frame -> True];
bands90[x_] = nlm4["MeanPredictionBands", ConfidenceLevel -> .9];
Show[ListPlot[data], 
  Plot[{nlm4[x], bands90[x]}, {x, 0, 40000}, Filling -> {2 -> {1}}], 
  PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, Frame -> True];
{bands95[x_], bands99[x_], bands999[x_]} = 
  Table[nlm4["MeanPredictionBands", 
    ConfidenceLevel -> cl], {cl, {.95, .99, .999}}];
Show[ListPlot[data], 
 Plot[{nlm4[x], bands90[x], bands95[x], bands99[x], bands999[x]}, {x, 
   0, 40000}, Filling -> {2 -> {1}, 3 -> {2}, 4 -> {3}, 5 -> {4}}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"model", "90% confidence bands", 
    "95% confidence bands", "99% confidence bands", 
    "99.9% confidence bands"}], PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, 
 Frame -> True]
```

Is there any other method that I could employ to do a quick copy-paste of graph/plots/etc from MMA to generic modules such as email

Comment: Select the cell and right click and save as PDF.

Comment: On macOS, I can select any part of the notebook (e.g. select both the figure and legend) and use Edit -> Copy As -> Bitmap.  The copy options differ from platform to platform, I think. E.g. macOS offers PDF because this is a native format for the platform and could likely be implemented with minimal effort.

Comment: Not exactly Mathematica-related, *per se*, but if you have a Mac you can use BetterTouchTool to make an easy trackpad shortcut (I use 4-finger force click) to screenshot a selected area and immediately copy the image to your clipboard. It's not necessarily the most elegant solution, but it's incredibly fast and WYSIWYG is always nice.